# Set default value of RadDatePicker to NULL when date is not set

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, telerik, telerik-grid

I'm binding the RadDatePicker to a viewModel dateTime property. when the property is null in database i get 01/01/0001. How to i change this behavior to just leave the date field blank..
example:

In database     ===>   experiation_date : NULL
In View(GUI)    ===>   experation_date  : 01/01/0001

Expected Result ===>   experation_date  :  {Blank}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the SelectedDate to null (and not DBNull):

```
RadDatePicker1.SelectedDate = null;
```

and in xaml set DateTimeWatermarkContent to the empty string:

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker x:Name="RadDatePicker1" DateTimeWatermarkContent="" />
```

Comment: How can i solve problem for <
telerik:DataFormDataField DataMemberBinding="{Binding ExpirationDate> im facing same problem for this

Comment: Yes i got solution for this problem...we just need to change datatype of that property which is bind for <telerik:DataFormDataField> control in view model.

Answer (score 1):

It is not always possible to change the Data Type from DateTime to DateTime? as a DateTime object might in fact be required. (A typical scenario is when your control is bound to a database object with a DateTime type but you are busy creating a new record in your control and so the value is still null at that point.) In such a case, it is possible to write a Value Converter as Paulo does in the following link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/default-date-value-01-01-001 (See his code for the EditDateConverter. It works just as-is...) I am pasting his code here for reference and in case that link stops working in future:

```
public class EditDateConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType().FullName == "System.DateTime")
        {
            var dt2 = (DateTime)value;
            if (dt2 != DateTime.MinValue)
                return value;
        }
        DateTime dt;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(value as string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal, out dt))
            return dt != DateTime.MinValue ? value : null;
        return dt;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null && targetType.FullName == "System.DateTime")
            return DateTime.MinValue;
        return value;
    }
}
```

To use it in a binding for your RadDatePicker, simply add the converter as a resource in your XAML and then add the converter to your binding.

In your XAML namespace declarations you have to add the namespace of your converter, for example:

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Converters"
```

And then in the Resources section of your XAML you would have:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:EditDateConverter x:Name="NullableDate"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you can simply add the following line to your binding on the control:

```
Converter={StaticResource NullableDate}
```

If you now have a null date the control will display the watermark (e.g. "Enter Date") rather than 01/01/0001.

Answer (score 0):

If you are bind not nullable datetime variable i.e (DateTime) to   control then it will use default 01/01/001 date instead of Empty....
So if you want the default value as a Empty then just change the datatype of your variable which is bound to  control to (DateTime?).....

DateTime ===> DateTime?

It works fine...

Thank you.!!!